# Mysql Turkish character encoding

Tags: java, mysql, character-encoding

I am trying to insert Turkish characters from Spring Boot application to mysql database which is on cloud right now. I connect to my database using following query:

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost/DB_NAME?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false
```

Also I changed my database encodings like

```
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  utf8
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    utf8
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
```

But still when I want to insert a key into database it writes like this:

```
NİŞ -> N%C4%B0%C5%9E
```

I am not sure what I should do and what am I missing right now. In my personal computer, everything works fine but in remote computer I have this issue. Should I clear the database or should change any configuration?

Comment: More likely, something is url-encoding your data before it even reaches MySQL, I'd look for the problem there.

Comment: How are you generating `%C4`, etc?  MySQL does _not_ generate such.  Nor can MySQL easily clean up that mess.